# How to do multi cell search for true or false, and return a single true or false in a different cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to return a True or False in a single cell if any of two other cells contain a keyword that I am looking for.

For example, if I am looking for the color red the result would look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIF.  In C2 put:

```
 =COUNTIF(A2:B2,$C$1)>0
```

And copy down.

[image]